# Double quotes inside double quotes in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to run a command that has double quotes inside it:

```
insdizi=`ps -ef| grep -v grep | grep asm_pmon_ | awk ' {print $2}'`
proddizi=`ps -ef | grep asm_smon_ | grep -v grep | cut -d"_" -f3`
insname=()
homename=()
sid=()

for i in $insdizi; do
insname+=( "$i" )
a=`ls -l /proc/${insname[ii]}/cwd | awk '{print ($NF) }' |sed 's#/dbs##'`
olsnodes="${a}/bin/olsnodes"
homename+=( "$olsnodes" )
ii=`expr $ii + 1`
done

ii=`expr $ii - 1`
for i in `seq 0 $ii`; do
nodeNum= "${olsnodes}"
nodeNumm= `bash -c "${nodeSayi} |grep -c '""'"`   
echo $nodeNumm 

 echo "nodeNumm= $nodeNumm"
  for node in `bash -c "${homename[i]}"`; do
echo $node

cokluBellekKontrol $node
cokluSessionSayi $node

 done
```

done

`olsnodes` variable is a command which is run from a directory like:

```
   /app/oracle/grid/bin/olsnodes
```

Here is what i need to run:

```
 /app/oracle/grid/bin/olsnodes | grep -c ""
```

I tried this:

```
 nodeNumm= `bash -c "${nodeNum} |grep -c '""'"`
```

But it gave me error:

```
"0: command not found."
```

**EDIT**

output of olsnodes is :

```
ax1
ax2
ax3
ax4
```

Also, i can grep the line count with this command:

```
/u01/app/11.2.0.4/grid/bin/olsnodes |grep -c ""
```

Comment: What is the ouput of `olsnodes` that you want to grep from?

Comment: I don't see any `"` in this output. What do you want to grep from these lines?

Comment: You don't see but i want it to grep line number.

Comment: Is the output of `olsnodes` command those 4 lines **as is**. I mean there are no quotes in the output.

Comment: Can you check my edit?

Comment: I see `grep -c ""` line but still its not making sense since there are no quotes in the output shown.

Comment: If you want just line count, I'd suggest `wc -l`.

Comment: that's an idea too, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single and double quotes don't nest with respect to each other. Only parenthesized and braced substitutions (`${}`, `$()`, `$(())`) do.

You can escape quotes within quotes with `\`.

```
nodeNumm= `bash -c "${nodeSayi} |grep -c '""'"`
```

should be

```
nodeNumm= $(bash -c "${nodeSayi} |grep -c '\"\"'")
```

Or should it? Did you want to do

```
grep -c ""
```

or

```
grep -c '""'
```

?

If the former, it could have been written simply as

```
grep -c ''
```

and there is no problem putting *that* in double quotes.

Then I suspect that will still not do what you expected, unless you expected it to:

- set variable `nodeNumm` to empty string for duration of the following,
- run the command,
- execute the output as a command.

If you wanted to set `nodeNumm` to the output of the command, correct syntax would be:

```
nodeNumm=$(bash -c "${nodeSayi} | grep -c '\"\"'")
```

There is however no point in running the `grep` in the subshell, which can get us rid of the outer quotes and the whole nesting problem. Just

```
nodeNumm=$(bash -c "${nodeSayi}" | grep -c '""')
```

Note, that I changed the process substitution from backquotes to `$()`. It's exactly because that nests correctly with respect to other process substitutions and to quotes.

Comment: That's the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark: I first wrote the answer assuming you wanted to run `grep -c '""'`, that is search for pairs of double quotes in the output. If you wanted to search for empty string (as your edit to the question suggests), empty string can be equivalently written as `''` and there are no quote nesting problems.

Comment: I wanted to run grep -c "" 
That works for now. Thanks for information.